# PHP get_contents() Error

Tags: php

I am getting following error when using PHP `get_contents()`:

What am i missing here? It work perfectly in Local Server with XAMPP.

PHP Version 5.3.29

SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.8b

> **Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]:** SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /home/XXXXXX/public_html/test.php on line 21
>
> **Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]:** Failed to enable crypto in /home/xxxxx/public_html/test.php on line 21
>
> **Warning: file_get_contents(https://.....XXXXXX) [function.file-get-contents]:** failed to open stream: operation failed

```
$url_api        = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$getResult = array( 
"ssl" => array( 
    "verify_peer"      => false, 
    "verify_peer_name" => false, 
),  
'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",    
    'header'=>"XXXXXX: xxxxxxxxxx\r\n"  
));
$getContext = stream_context_create($getResult);
$getResponse = file_get_contents($url_api, false, $getContext);
```

Comment: do you have openssl extension installed for your php?

Comment: YES! 
OpenSSL support enabled

I found it in phpinfo().

I added PHP version above... Is it because of lower php version?

I tested with CURL and it never get any info returned. :)

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is On?

Comment: YES it is on for both Local and Master Value.

Comment: Not so sure, but [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54511) is the similar bug

Comment: Yap. No idea what is issue here? Do you think it is issue occurred because of PHP version?

Comment: I just tried your script with my php (v 5.5.31) and it worked

Comment: My php v is 5.3.29. Can i share link with you in some other way privately?

Comment: Didn't understood what link? You mean $url_api? Yes, you can, but I dunno how to do it with stackoverflow :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111307/discussion-between-user1464262-and-sly).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that the problem is in your code. I tested it on my Laravel vagrant box and it worked perfectly. I think that the problem is in the data of your $url_api variable.

Comment: I tested it in my local server and it is working just find but when i test in LIVE server it is throwing above error. I checked SSL and things all good there.

Answer (score -1):

Check your php.ini file, uncomment

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

If this already been done, check your firewall if it allows the connection.
Simple way is to use `telnet`.

Comment: Viyog, Please check you the firewall from your host server to the server you want to open stream on. The firewall should be open on port 433 both way.